# Can I create table in MySQL with adding columns in information_schema table directly

Tags: mysql, information-schema

is there is opportunity create table by query to infirmation_schema without
 `create table ...` ?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without `create table ...`???

Simple answer **NO**. Sole purpose of `CREATE TABLE` statement is to create a database table. In general `CREATE Object` statement are for creating DB objects. There is no other alternative way present for this unless *you develop your own RDBMS product*.

In case you are confused, read [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) and as it clearly says

> **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** provides access to database metadata, information
>   about the MySQL server such as the name of a database or table, the
>   data type of a column, or access privileges.

And yes it's Read-Only.

Answer (score 0):

It is called **information_schema** not create_schema. So you can only read information there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, the Information_schema DB is read only.
But in MySQL, the views are not sequenced. For example in this DDL : "create view q1 as select a.* from q2 as a inner join t1 as b on a.col1=b.col1".
You cannot create q1 without creating first q2. If you extract the DDL's from information.views, the Q1 DDL comes before the Q2 DDL.
To resolve simply this problem we need only to add a column auto_increment to the table information_schema.views, or better in the table information_schema.innodb_sys_tables.